# how to install gfortran package on ubuntu 12.04 offline pc

Tags: 12.04, installation, package-management, fortran

I have downloaded gfortran package from there site and now looking for installing it on the offline ubuntu 12.04 pc... please don't close this question stating possible duplicate. I am looking for steps to install the package by extracting and installing it. I don't want to use get-offline neither keryx nor to use some other online ubuntu systems. I am very much clear.. I have the downloaded package and I am looking forward for the steps to install the package with out accessing internet. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install a downloaded `deb` package using `dpkg`:

```
sudo dpkg -i gfortran_x.y.z_arch.deb
```

However, it will probably tell you that one or more dependencies are unavailable, which you will then need to also download before you can install it (note that `gfortran` is a dummy package that just provides dependency on the actual compiler package, currently `gfortran-4.6`, in order to make installing multiple different versions possible).

You can see the dependencies of any single package with:

```
dpkg -I gfortran_x.y.z_arch.deb | grep Depends
```

`gfortran` has a *lot* of dependencies (`gcc` and lots of associated libraries). If you don't want to use specialised tools, you'll either spend a long time getting extra files, or try installing `gfortran` on a similarly configured, internet connected machine and see what has to be downloaded. The tool `apt-rdepends` might be helpful for listing all the recursive dependencies of a package.

Comment: guys thanks! I had to install some big list of dependencies for installing gfortran on ubuntu 12.04 and finally it worked!